# Is there a tag that can be used for questions about letters/characters?

Tags: support, tags

I'm looking for a tag that can be applied to questions about letters/characters (such as *How did the names of the letters in the English language come about*, or *Why do capital I's and small l's look the same with some fonts?*)? Not sure if there is one already out there and I haven't seen it, or if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to https://english.stackexchange.com/tags you can search for tags.

Tags currently existing which include the string `letter` are [letter-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-writing), [silent-letters](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silent-letters) and [letter-names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-names).

We do actually have a question [Where did the names of English letters come from, and why are they all monosyllabic (except for "w")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37411) which is treated as a duplicate of [Pronunciation of the English alphabet](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20803).

Your question about the similarity of I and l in certain typefaces is not restricted to English and is off-topic. It **might** be on-topic on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), but it's probably opinion-based.

Comment: weird.... there's no [font](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font) tag.

Comment: @Mitch That's because fonts are not part of the English language.

Comment: Sure, but spelling and punctuation are not part of the English language either. Yes, I know that is disingenuous, and also font questions should go to [graphicdesign.SE] but there are totally on-topic questions on ELU about handwriting and strange symbols and  shorthand and such, so it is plausible that font questions might at one time have appeared here.